# Traceroute Implementation on Python

Tags: python, scapy, traceroute

So I've been trying to understand how this code works using Scapy on Python as I am trying to create a similar traceroute for my project. However, this does not work. I tried printing the reply type and it shows '11' in between hops. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this or does this whole thing just not work?

```
hostname = "172.217.17.46" #Change that to user input later

    print("Destination: " + hostname)

    for i in range(1,28):
        pkt = IP(dst=hostname, ttl=i)/ UDP(dport=33434)
    
        #packet is sent
        reply = sr1(pkt, verbose=0)
        #print(reply.type)
    
        #No reply
        if reply is None:
            print("hi")
            break
            
        elif reply.type == 3:
            #reached
            print("Done", reply.src)
            break
            #continue
        else:
            #print(reply.type)
            print ("%d hops away: " %i, reply.src)
            #continue
        break
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not work"? There's at least two problems: you haven't set a timeout for `sr1`, so it will potentially hang indefinitely. You also have a `break` at the bottom of the loop, so it will never get past the first iteration. Once you fix those two things, (along with getting rid of the `break` in the `reply is None` case), it works.

Comment: For reference, [here's a simple traceroute](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/c407d7c592864fadc3f72959bb616e4a) I wrote a few months ago, and [here's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249905/simplified-windows-tracert-command) a more complicated version that mimics the actual command.